# How to set up an XPRA proxy server for multiple users, reverse proxied with Apache

Tags: remote-desktop

On an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system I would like to configure the ["XPRA proxy server"](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/blob/master/docs/Usage/Proxy-Server.md) in the following manner:

0. XPRA should be accessed via its HTML5 client so that users don't need XPRA on their machines.
1. Users shall be able to connect to XPRA via the URL `https://xpra.example.net`, instead of `http://example.net:14500`. I.e. the XPRA HTML service should be reverse-proxied by the (Apache) webserver so that HTTPS requests to the `xpra.example.net` virtual host get forwarded to `localhost:14500`. I could not find any descriptions of how to do this: most likely one must use websockets.
2. Each user shall get access to his/her graphical desktop. I figured out that if I start on the server XPRA manually as `xpra start-desktop --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:14500 --start-child=startlxde` (for the LXDE desktop) then I can indeed connect via the HTML5 client using `http://example.net:14500` but this quickly gets clumsy as one needs to SSH into the server first to run the `xpra start-desktop` command there.
3. The proxy server shall be started/stopped as a system service. There is indeed a `/lib/systemd/system/xpra.service` service file but I am not sure whether it is correctly configured for these requirements above.

I have tried my best to figure all this out from the [XPRA documentation](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/tree/master/docs) but failed. Has anyone succeeded in setting up XPRA this way? If yes, any help would be much appreciated.

**PS** I would have liked to tag this question with "xpra" but don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I'd like the same, but right now I'll settle for xpra htm5 working on Ubuntu 20.04 at all because I have been unable to make that combo work so far for  aarch64 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in basically the same situation, except I want to use nginx. I think the xpra proxy server may be able to support such a setup, but I'm not fully sure, it's also possible that the version in ubuntu 20.04 is too old to make it work correctly. I don't seem to be able to chain the two xpra layers, and I can't control what the web UI does (it tends to start a new session when I tell it to connect to an existing one, for example).

What I ended up with is having multiple virtual subdirectories on the webserver, with each proxying to a different upstream xpra instance. This seems to work adequately.

I still have a couple of minor issues, like the DPI is sometimes messed up, the PAM authentication doesn't work when I launch a user's desktop through a systemd service, but these can probably be solved or worked around with a bit of time.